# Domains, hosting and the law

Tags: domains, web-hosting, legal

Currently I live in the Netherlands. So, what if..

- I register a .CN domainname and upload my website to it. Under which law is my website? The Chinese or the Dutch?
- and I host my website at the Isle of Man, under which law is my website? The Chinese, the Dutch or Isle of man?

Comment: Nice username ;)

Comment: OT: Thank you, did you watch the Naked gun? ;-)

Comment: I did. The Enrico Pallazzo part is one of my favorites. :)

Comment: Bah.. One day you talk about him and a few days later he ain't no more :-(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All of the above.

You have to make sure you follow all of the rules set forth by the Chinese Gov't or whomever controls the .cn TLD. If you do not meet their criteria for use of a .cn domain name they can revoke it from you.

If your business, or you if you aren't a registered business, is located in the Netherlands, then you are subject to their laws.

If you host your website in the Isle of Man you also must follow their laws as they can shut down your service for violating it even if you aren't based there.

Comment: Maaaaaan, this really creates some problems. In the Netherlands software patents do NOT exist. Innovation ftw!! But when I place my website under a .com domain and use a CDN I am bound to the laws of at least 3 countries :(